# Which is the most efficient way to compairing all values (sets) of a dict in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, collections

I'm trying to compare every pair of values in a python dict. The values associated to each key is a list, and i have to obtain the common elements between every pair of lists. The dict structure is:

```
fruits = {
     'orange': [3, 5, 7, 2, 11],
     'apple':  [4, 7, 2, 9, 1],
     'grape':  [18, 6, 8, 4]
}
```

And the result i want:

```
{
    'orange': { 'apple':  2 },
    'apple':  { 'orange': 2, 'grape': 1 },
    'grape':  { 'apple': 1 }
}
```

I have tried to do it using dict comprehesion and deque data structure, but still not so efficient:

deque:

```py
deque_fruits = deque(fruits.keys())
fruits_copy = fruits.copy()
result = {}

while len(deque_fruits) > 0:
        fruit = deque_fruits.popleft()
        values = fruits_copy[fruit]
        del fruit__copy[fruit]

        for aux_fruit, aux_values in fruits_copy.items():
            intersection = len(set(values)&set(aux_values))
            if intersection > 0:
                result[fruit][aux_fruit] = intersection
                result[aux_fruit][fruit] = intersection
```

dict comprehesion

```py
result = {
        fruit: {
            aux_fruit: len(set(values)&set(aux_values)) 
            for aux_fruit, aux_values in fruits.items() if fruit != aux_fruit and len(set(values)&set(aux_values)) > 0 
        }
        for fruit, valuesin fruits.items()
    }
```

Any idea of how to speed up this? Got ~84000 elems and each one a list of ~100-200 values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you've already calculated the common elements for `fruit-a` and `fruit-b`, then you don't need to do it again for `fruit-b` and `fruit-a`. Looking at you code, it seems that you do.

Comment: On deque implementation i've tried to not compare two fruits sets if they have been already compared, and assign both values at the same time. On dict comprehesion idk the way to do it. Still dict comprehesion is a bit faster than deque one (5.5it/sec vs 3.5it/sec)

Comment: Are there 84000 items in *fruits*? If yes, it would mean 3.5e9 combinations, which is huge! How big are the numbers in the lists? Are they bounded (eg. all less than 1000)?

Comment: How do you deal with the case where orange and apples have two common members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a faster implementation:

```py
# Precompute the sets and the items
fruitItems = {name: set(value) for name,value in fruits.items()}.items()

result = dict()
for name1, value1 in fruitItems:
    tmpRes = dict()
    for name2, value2 in fruitItems:
        count = len(value1 & value2)
        if name1 != name2 and count > 0:
            tmpRes[name2] = count
    result[name1] = tmpRes
```

This code is 4 times faster with 50 fruits and 10 integers/list.
Note that using PyPy or Cython improve a bit the execution time.
If all list integers are quite small and bounded, there is a much faster implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much Jérôme! The lists that i'm working with are list of Strings, so not much more to do with that. I used fruits and ints as an example.

Answer (score 0):

@Jérôme Richard's solution computes N^2 intersections and handles N^2 - N items, although `intersection(set1, set2) == intersection(set2, set1)`. This can be cut down to N*(N-1)/2 operations, which is 25% to 50% (for large N) of the original effort. So to say, it's traversing only the upper half of an NxN matrix, minus the N diagonal elements. `defaultdict` is needed as the assignment of the counterpart is not in sequence of occurrance.

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    def compare_sets():
        fruits = {
         'orange': [3, 5, 7, 2, 11],
         'apple':  [4, 7, 2, 9, 1],
         'grape':  [18, 6, 8, 4],
         'pear':   [4, 16, 7, 5]
        }

        # precompute the sets and the items
        fruit_items = {name: set(set) for name,set in fruits.items()}.items()

        # create dict of dicts
        result = defaultdict(dict)
        n = len(fruit_items)
        # working with indices instead of items to avoid duplicate pairings
        for i in range(n-1):
            name1, set1 = fruit_items[i]
            tmp_result = dict()
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                name2, set2 = fruit_items[j]
                count = len(set1 & set2) # intersection
                if count > 0:
                    tmp_result[name2] = count
                    result[name2][name1] = count  # counterpart
            result[name1] = tmp_result
```